# Can i install foxpro and sql-server both in same PC User without any conflicts?

Tags: sql, sql-server, installation, foxpro

In my Office is ready installed foxpro database with old visual foxpro information system. but in new information system we need develop with visual studio and install Microsoft SqlServer Database. 
Can i install foxpro and sql-server both in same PC User without any conflicts?

Comment: Why would you not be able to do so? They're nowhere near the same thing, they have nothing to do with each other, and there's no reason to think they'd be a conflict any more than installing MS Office and MS SQL Server.

Comment: Memory is always a potential conflict...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely, people have been doing it for years. Especially those people who use Visual FoxPro as the front end and connect to SQL Server data.

At some points I have had Visual FoxPro 6 and 9, a couple of versions of SQL Server and PostGres all on the same machine.

Visual FoxPro databases are just stored in the file system as files. There is no 'server' in the sense of SQL Server, Oracle, DB2 etc. Which is one of the problems with it in the present day.